# Moving Feature Class to Different Feature Dataset within Same File Geodatabase using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, feature-class, code-review

I want to progammatically move a feature class into a different feature dataset within the same file geodatabase. I'm wondering if there is a way of doing this without including code to rename and delete data.

My current code looks something like this:

```
for fc in fc_list:
        out_fc = fc+'_1'
        arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(fc, archive, out_fc)
        arcpy.Delete_management(fc)
        arcpy.Rename_management(out_fc, fc)
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you have the best arcpy solution available.  Why not just open catalog, select the feature classes, and drag them into the new feature dataset?

Comment: it's in a script that updates one FGDB to match another, and it checks/updates the locations of several hundred feature classes on a weekly basis. i was thinking there would be a faster way than copying/deleting large feature classes. i'd prefer to be able to just switch the feature dataset and eliminate all that work.

Comment: Well, if you know any .net you could probably do it by scripting the moving of the feature classes through catalog.  I don't know of an arcpy move data command and I couldn't find one when I searched.  You could try switching over to [arcpy.CopyFeatures_management()](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/copy-features.htm).  I think it's a bit faster than fc to fc conversion

Comment: You could of course put what you are doing in a function, but that will at most save you some typing. Or find a way of only updating the records that have changed.